# How to check a markdown-encoded field in PHP?

Tags: php, markdown

Is there some best practice to check the consistency of a field (received from an HTML form) that is supposed to be Markdown-formatted text?

Most importantly, I would like to ensure the submitted text does not contain any HTML/script.

At the moment, I'm achieving this with PHP `strip_tags()` function.

Although the main idea of markdown format is to be text-only, I'm unsure this function will not corrupt Markdown formatting.

(What about `<http://www.example.com>` syntax for instance ?)

Comment: I think you might find this Github repository useful for parsing MD text : https://github.com/erusev/parsedown

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Parsedown API does not offer any way to check validity of md text. And re-encoding some text already md-formatted will definitely corrupt the data...

Comment: Have you _tried it_ with `<http://www.example.com>`?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you read [this article](https://michelf.ca/blog/2010/markdown-and-xss/). Striping raw HTML does **not** provide any security. Plain old Markdown is just as "unsafe". You need an HTML sanitizer. One is recommended in the aforementioned article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking Markdown validity is indeed tricky.
Here is the only way I came up with to make sure the Markdown-encoded text stored is safe:

1. parse MarkDown text to HTML
2. Sanitize HTML (for instance with HTMLPurifier)
3. convert result back to Markdown

Note: if you only need a subset of markdown (like the mini-markdown stackoverflow is using for users comments) involving only **bold**, _italic_, `code` and [links](http://www.example.com), then using `strip_tags` is enough (it could result in changes in the output, but at least it is safe).